# How to build a model class dynamically in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to build a model class dynamically in Spark and Scala when I have more than 100 fields attributes.Like we are building model/Pojo in Core Java using Thrift or Xml or JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

https://github.com/julianpeeters/case-class-generator#case-class-generator

Dynamically defines and loads Scala classes at runtime. Useful for turning JSON schemas into Scala case classes on the fly.
Allows runtime data to serve as Scala case class definitions:

Features :

1. Case classes defined and loaded at runtime
2. Pseudo Type-Provider via
   type alias

Dependency :

```
"com.julianpeeters" %% "case-class-generator" % "0.7.1"
```

This project also supports scala 2.11 as well.